# How to Insert React Component Inside `leaflet-overlay-pane` using react-leaflet (core)?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm working on a project where I'm using react and react-leaflet to create a map application. I have a requirement to insert a custom React component, wrapped in a `<div>`, inside the `leaflet-overlay-pane`. Specifically, I need to integrate this React component seamlessly into the Leaflet map using react-leaflet. The component should take in the coordinates to position itself on the map.

Can anyone provide a sample or point to an example?